# Building a Redis cluster using docker images on top of Vagrant: Cannot ping machines

Tags: docker, vagrant

I'm trying to build a simple redis cluster locally on OSX, using docker inside virtualbox VMS. Specifically, I want to create a master redis node (192.168.0.100) with two slaves (.101 and .102). This involves configuring each machine and issuing a command to each slave to tell it who the master is in the key-value-store relationship.

This worked great, until I decided to make my configuration more flexible by doing some programmatic stuff inside my Vagrantfile. The result is that I am unable to even ping any of the machines beside .102, let alone uses redis-cli commands (for example, `redis-cli -h 192.168.0.100 INFO` to see that the master has slaves set up correctly)

My goals/constraints:

- Run docker inside a virtualbox VM: I saw several ways to do this when reading the docs. I chose the way I do it because I don't want to refer to a ton of external files.
- Run a sequence of commands on each VM after configuration to set slaves and whatnot.
- I'd prefer not to just use boot2docker as I have a bunch other stuff I'm gonna be adding... twemproxy, sentinel and I want to simulate a production environment at least a little bit.

What am I doing wrong in my new file?

EDIT: I've investigated a bit more. One thing I tried was destroying all images, then running the old vagrant file to build the machines, and then reloading them with the new vagrant file. In this scenario, the machines worked, though each time I'd see authentication failure messages like `redis1: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...` after the machine had gone up. I was able to ping the machine no problem though.

---

New Vagrantfile (uses config file below):

```
require './config.rb'
include RedisClusterConfig

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
    config.vm.provider "virtualbox"

    ## Redis Nodes (Can define multiple triplets) ##
    for node in RedisClusterConfig.redisNodes
        config.vm.define node.name do |a|
            a.vm.hostname = node.name
            a.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

            # Skip checking for an updated Vagrant box
            a.vm.box_check_update = false

            # Networking
            a.vm.network :private_network, ip: node.address
            a.ssh.forward_agent = true
            a.ssh.insert_key = false

            # Set up docker with 'redis' image
            a.vm.provision "docker" do |d|
                d.images = ["redis"]
                d.run "redis", name: "redis", args: "-p "+node.port+":"+node.port
            end

            # Additional configuration
            a.trigger.after [:up, :resume, :reload, :provision] do
                # Master/slave
                unless node.slaveOfAddress.nil?
                    system("redis-cli -h " + node.address + " SLAVEOF " + node.slaveOfAddress + " " + node.slaveOfPort)
                    puts "Finished setting up slave node: " + node.name
                else
                    puts "Finished setting up master node: " + node.name
                end
            end
        end 
    end

end
```

config.rb:

```
module RedisClusterConfig
    attr_reader :redisNodes 

    RedisNode = Struct.new("RedisNode", :name, :address, :port, :slaveOfAddress, :slaveOfPort)

    p = "6379" # Default redis port
    baseAddr = "192.168.0."

    # Define a triplet
    redis0 = RedisNode.new("redis0", baseAddr + "100", p, nil, nil)
    redis1 = RedisNode.new("redis1", baseAddr + "101", p, baseAddr + "100", p)
    redis2 = RedisNode.new("redis2", baseAddr + "102", p, baseAddr + "100", p)

    @redisNodes = [redis0, redis1, redis2]
end
```

---

Old Vagrantfile:

```
# Make sure you have triggers plugin:
#     vagrant plugin install vagrant-triggers
#
# TODO:
# - We really would like to run some shell commands after everything is done, not after each machine is provisioned

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
    config.vm.provider "virtualbox"

    ## Redis Nodes ##

    ### Master Node###
    config.vm.define "redis0" do |a|
        a.vm.hostname = "redis0"
        a.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

        # Skip checking for an updated Vagrant box
        a.vm.box_check_update = false

        # Networking
        a.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.0.100"
        a.ssh.forward_agent = true
        a.ssh.insert_key = false

        a.vm.provision "docker" do |d|
          d.images = ["redis"]
          d.run "redis",
            name: "redis",
            args: "-p 6379:6379"
        end
    end

    ### Slave Nodes ###
    config.vm.define "redis1" do |a|
        a.vm.hostname = "redis1"
        a.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

        # Skip checking for an updated Vagrant box
        a.vm.box_check_update = false

        # Networking
        a.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.0.101"
        a.ssh.forward_agent = true
        a.ssh.insert_key = false

        a.vm.provision "docker" do |d|
          d.images = ["redis"]
          d.run "redis",
            name: "redis",
            args: "-p 6379:6379"
        end
    end

    config.vm.define "redis2" do |a|
        a.vm.hostname = "redis2"
        a.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

        # Skip checking for an updated Vagrant box
        a.vm.box_check_update = false

        # Networking
        a.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.0.102"
        a.ssh.forward_agent = true
        a.ssh.insert_key = false

        a.vm.provision "docker" do |d|
          d.images = ["redis"]
          d.run "redis",
            name: "redis",
            args: "-p 6379:6379"
        end
    end

    # After everything else has finished provisioning...
    config.trigger.after [:up, :resume, :reload] do
        # Configuring redis master/slave triplet
        system('echo Configuring redis master/slave triplet...')
        system('redis-cli -h 192.168.0.101 SLAVEOF 192.168.0.100 6379')
        system('redis-cli -h 192.168.0.102 SLAVEOF 192.168.0.100 6379')
    end

end
```

Comment: // , It's been nearly a year. Did you ever find the solution to this, or did you have to re-do it from the ground up?

Comment: I gave up and went straight to building VMs in Google Compute Engine, where the actual system lives. I'm rebuilding the system now to use Kubernetes (probably through the managed version, Google Container Engine), and I assume this would make the vagrant part easier, since Kubernetes fixes Docker's broken networking.

Comment: // , I thought Swarm fixed Docker's broken networking?